# Angular - Whats wrong with this $rootscope variable

Tags: angularjs

I've created a `$rootscope` variable on a controller that doesn't seem to work as I'd expect.

As a simplified example:

```
function MainCtrl($rootScope, $location) {

var self = this;
$rootScope.pageComingFrom = '/';

self.goToLoginPage = function(){
    $rootScope.pageComingFrom = $location.$$path;
}

self.handleRequest = function(){
    $location.path($rootScope.pageComingFrom);
}

}
```

The issue if i call `goToLoginPage()` first, then when i go into `handleRequest()` the variable `$rootScope.pageComingFrom` is shown as the default `'/'`.

Why is this/where am i going wrong?

Thanks.

(Also is it better performance wise to create a service to set and get this variable instead - I'm only using on 1 controller)?

Comment: Did you instantiate multiple instances of this controller, by any chance?

Comment: Why do you use the undocumented $$path attribute rather than the documented path() getter? Do you, by any chance, reload the page between the two calls?

Comment: Ah ok - yes, the page is being reloaded. But the two methods are called after each other.

Comment: Ok - got it, I was recalling the controller, so reseting the value to `'/'`. Also have updated to use correct `$location.path()`
If i'm using this in one controller is using $rootScope ok, or should I create a service?

Comment: Every time you reload the page, the application restarts from scratch, and everything you stored in memory is lost. $rootScope is not a persistent store. If you need the path to be persistent, then pass it as a path parameter somehow, or store it in a cookie, or in local storage.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks and would you say performance wise local storage or rootScope better. I'm literally saving the URL so the user can be taken back after they login/register.

Comment: It's not a performance problem. It simply won't work with $rootScope if you need to reload the page and still get back the pageComingFrom. Because rootScope store things in memory. And the memory is flushed when you reload the page. Make something that works. Then, and only then, if you have a performance problem, start thinking about performance.

Comment: Great - makes sense. Thanks!